# What's the probabality of at most two consecutive heads in N coin flips?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, recursion

I tried solving using recursion but am not sure whether my answer is correct.

I tried using 
P(N) = P(N-1)*0.25*1 (For the last two TT)
       + P(N-1)*0.25*1 (For the last two HT)
       + P(N-1)*0.25*1 (For the last two TH)
       + P(N-1)*0.25*0.5 (For the last two HH, since it can be followed only by T)

Comment: Post your ideas, it is more useful to discuss them rather than showing a solution out of the blue

Comment: Post your answer, and how you arrived at it.  Then we can either verify it or show where you may have gone wrong, and why.

Comment: Added what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's count the toss sequences with no triple $HHH$.  Let $T_n$ be the number of such, of length $n$. Of course, the answer you seek is $\frac {T_n}{2^n}$.

Let $A_n$ be those "good" sequences of length $n$ that end in $T$, let $B_n$ be those that end in $TH$, and let $C_n$ be those that end in $THH$.  Then $$T_n=A_n+B_n+C_n$$ Furthermore, $$A_n=T_{n-1}\quad B_n=A_{n-1}=T_{n-2}\quad C_n=B_{n-1}=T_{n-2}$$  Whence $$T_n=T_{n-1}+T_{n-2}+T_{n-3}$$  Clearly we have $T_1=2,\;T_2=4,\;T_3=7$

I'm not aware of a pleasant closed formula, though of course standard methods will give an expression in terms of the roots of the associated cubic.  See [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TribonacciNumber.html) for some details.  Of course it's easy to implement the recursion for modest $N$.